# How do I connect to a Teradata via ODBC in code?

Tags: c++, database, odbc, teradata

The connection string specified is:

*Provider=Teradata;DBCName=dbc_name;Database=database_name; Uid=user_name;Pwd=password;*

I installed Teradata ODBC client version 15.1 and setup a connection to it via the control panel.

When use the code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <Windows.h>
#include <sql.h>
#include <sqlext.h>
#include <string>

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    SQLHANDLE hdbc = SQL_NULL_HANDLE;
    SQLHANDLE henv = SQL_NULL_HANDLE;
    SQLRETURN retval = SQL_SUCCESS;

    retval = SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_ENV, SQL_NULL_HANDLE, &henv);
    if (retval != SQL_SUCCESS) {
        printf("SQLAllocHandle SQL_HANDLE_ENV failed! Result = %d\n", retval);
    }

    retval = SQLSetEnvAttr(henv, SQL_ATTR_ODBC_VERSION, (SQLPOINTER)SQL_OV_ODBC3, 0);
    if (retval != SQL_SUCCESS) {
        printf("SQLSetEnvAttr SQL_ATTR_ODBC_VERSION failed! Result = %d\n", retval);
    }

    SQLINTEGER output_nts, autocommit;
    retval = SQLGetEnvAttr(henv, SQL_ATTR_ODBC_VERSION, &output_nts, 0, 0);

    retval = SQLSetEnvAttr(henv, SQL_ATTR_OUTPUT_NTS, (SQLPOINTER)SQL_TRUE, 0);
    if (retval != SQL_SUCCESS) {
        printf("SQLSetEnvAttr SQL_ATTR_OUTPUT_NTS failed! Result = %d\n", retval);
    }

    retval = SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, henv, &hdbc);
    if (retval != SQL_SUCCESS) {
        printf("SQLAllocHandle SQL_HANDLE_DBC failed! Result = %d\n", retval);
    }

    SQLCHAR szConn[1024];
    SWORD cbConn = 0;

    std::string connectionString("Provider=teradata;DBCName=myLocalTDcop;database=myDatabaseName;uid=myUID;pwd=myPwd;");

    retval = SQLDriverConnect(hdbc, NULL, (SQLCHAR*)connectionString.c_str(), SQL_NTS, szConn, 1024, &cbConn, SQL_DRIVER_NOPROMPT);
    if (retval != SQL_SUCCESS) {
        printf("SQLDriverConnect failed! Result = %d\n", retval);
    }
}
```

The SQLDriverConnect command always returns -1.

Am I doing something wrong with the connection string?

Update:
Using SQLGetDiagRec I have obtained the error message:

*The driver returned invalid (or failed to return) SQL_DRIVER_ODBC_VER: 03.80*

However, if I change the ODBC version to SQL_OV_ODBC3_80 then I get the error message:

*[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] The driver doesn't support the version of ODBC behavior that the application requested (see SQLSetEnvAttr).*

and then:

*The driver returned invalid (or failed to return) SQL_DRIVER_ODBC_VER: 03.80*

Is this to do with the ODBC version of 15.10?  I have looked at the documentation but cannot see where the ODBC version is specified.  Is there a way to check it in Windows?

Comment: It seems unlikely that the user id is `myUID` and the password is `myPwd`. Are you supplying the correct values? Also, you can use `SQLGetDiagRec` to get an informative error message.

Comment: I have changed the user name and password (probably not allowed to post them on a public forum).  Anyone running this sample code would need to change them to be whatever is relevant for their ODBC setup.

Comment: but thanks for the tip about SQLGetDiagRec!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had not added the correct directory to the Path environmental variable!!!!